# Does what='char' works for read.csv function?

Tags: r, csv

The basic format for scan function in R to read a file with characters is represented like this 
 a<- scan(file.choose(),what='char',sep=',').

I have a csv file with ***names*** as a separate column. Can i use what='char' in read.csv. If yes, how to use. If not how to read ***names*** column?

Comment: The standard way to read a `csv` file would usually be `read.csv` not `scan`.....

Comment: In `read.csv` (or any of the `read.*` family) you could use the "colClasses" parameter. And you should note that if you said `what='numeric'`, the function would have assumed "character" because the type of the string `"numeric"` is "character". The strings are not evaluated. Most people using `scan` will use `what=""` when they seek "character".

Answer (score 3):

There is an entire `R` manual on  importing and exporting data

https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-data.html

`read.table` (or more specifically `read.csv`, which is `read.table` with the default separator being a comma) are the functions you are looking for.

```
a <- read.csv(yourfile)
```